# Get a bot [python] to input data into a website

Tags: python, html

I have just started to look into Python.

Site: http://toolserver.org/~diberri/cgi-bin/html2wiki/index.cgi

Is it possible for a bot to put data in the top box, maybe tick a box or something, and click the button at the bottom "convert"?

Oh and also, under the Options header, there is a box where you can choose various options. How exactly do you get the bot to choose one of them?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any serious research first before asking?

Comment: When I first created this question, for some reason it was linking me to IRC bots. So that's not what I had in mind

I have searched google, but I wasn't sure what exactly to search for. "How to make a bot input data onto a website"?, "Make a bot access a web page"?. But yes, I have looked.

Is there any module I could use/documentation I can read?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047790/how-can-i-input-data-into-a-webpage-to-scrape-the-resulting-output-using-python, maybe

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can but you will not input HTML code with your bot. If you look at the source code for the page you will see:

```
<form method="post" action="index.cgi">
<fieldset style="display:none">
  <input type="hidden" name="m" value="convert" />
</fieldset> 
...
```

It does say that the form uses the method post to this uri:  http://toolserver.org/~diberri/cgi-bin/html2wiki/index.cgi

So now you can look at urllib2, [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) which is the python lib for http requests. And create your post request with the parameter you want.

E.g:

```
params = {
  'dialect' : googlecode,
  'uri' : myuri
}
```

You will need a header, telling the server who is doing the request:

E.g:

```
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
```

Something like this:

```
u = urllib2.urlopen(' http://toolserver.org/~diberri/cgi-bin/html2wiki/index.cgi', params)
h.request('POST', ' http://toolserver.org/~diberri/cgi-bin/html2wiki/index.cgi', params, headers)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand your response. Sorry.

Comment: TO be more specific, your second line. What do you mean by "headers"?

Comment: I suggest you learn about http: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/ because this is quite easy when you know it.

Comment: and uri, what is that. I'm such a newb :(